# Angular 8: Have Parent Component detect when User clicks out of Child Component Textbox

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have a Parent Component and a Child Component with Formbuilder and ZipCode textbox.

How do I make it so, when user clicks out of the Child Component Textbox,  Parent Component will know?
Need to run business logic after user clicks out of textbox. Currently textbox is based off Material Angular wrapper.

Child Component has Formbuilder and many textboxes, sample below

```
this.editAddressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   'city': [null,[Validators.maxLength(50)]],
   'zipCode': [null,[Validators.maxLength(10)]],


<app-input-textbox class = "zipcodeclass" div="zipcode" formControlName = "zipCode">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to emit an event to the parent on `blur` event.

In the HTML template, add `(blur)="onBlur()"`, and a template reference on every `input` (let's say `#templateReference1`, `#templateReference2` and `#templateReference3`)

Then in the child element:

```
@Output() noInputFocused: = new EventEmitter();

@ViewChild('templateReference1') templateReference1: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('templateReference2') templateReference2: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('templateReference3') templateReference3: ElementRef;

inputs;

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.inputs = [templateReference1, templateReference2, templateReference3];
}

onBlur() {
    if(this.inputs.map(x => x.nativeElement).indexOf(this.document.activeElement) < 0) {
        this.noInputFocused.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: accepted answer, miswrote question so another question here thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779037/angular-8-grandparent-component-detect-when-user-clicks-out-of-grandchild-compo